Dnsmasq: exclude certain subdomains from custom routing
I'm using Dnsmasq to route the names of services hosted on a server to localhost, so it doesn't reach out through the internet to them. I had done so like this:
address=/.sub.ourdomain.com/127.0.0.1

However, I was reminded that some services on this server do talk to other servers on our network. I'd love to be able to specify rules like what I have below, but don't know if it's possible, or what the syntax is.
address=/.oneapp.sub.ourdomain.com/<default routing>
address=/.sub.ourdomain.com/127.0.0.1

I tried ending the oneapp line with / or /#. With /, ping comes back with "Name or service not known", and with /#, DnsMasq reports an error during startup.
Is there a way to opt certain subdomains out of an address directive, forwarding them to the other name servers configured in resolv.conf?
